# Правила наполнения токена клеймами

Tags: oauth2, oidc

Подскажите годные статьи или ссылку на пункт в спецификации, где описано как правильно наполнять токен клеймами в зависимости от скопов и иных возможных факторов, так к примеру пермиссий клиента или же каких либо аттрибутных составов пользователя будь то роль к примеру...

Делаю Identity сервер, стоит вопрос как правильно наполнять токен в зависимости от переданных скопов, и остальных факторов.